SAM 2.1 what is causing hydra.errors.MissingConfigException: Primary config module 'sam2' not found?
I am trying to fine tune the new SAM 2.1 segmentation model using the roboflow guide given here: Sam 2.1 roboflow guide
This code runs all fine when using google collab and no errors are encountered. As soon as I run the exact same code provided on my local machine is gives the following error when running the training code command:
!python training/train.py -c 'configs/train.yaml' --use-cluster 0 --num-gpus 1
I get the following error when running on windows 10, using vscode:
hydra.errors.MissingConfigException: Primary config module 'sam2' not found.
Check that it's correct and contains an __init__.py file

my working directory:
C:\..\SAM_2_1\sam2


